# Edit icon Underneath Each Weblink

Tags: css, joomla

I added Weblinks to my website as I have done for years.

The Weblinks show up at the page just fine, but underneath each link an edit button appears that anyone can edit each link. I have spent 2 days chasing the answer...

I just want the normal links to appear and not the edit icons underneath.

www.ignacioval.com/contact/iv-links

Any suggestions How to get rid of these edit icons underneath each Joomla 3+ link?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, the good news is that not anybody can really change your links. People have to be logged in to do that, and then I presume have the right permissions. But the question is of course, why do the edit buttons show at all. Hm. Have you tried asking in the [Joomla](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions) site?

Comment: I will now that you make mention of it - Thank you

Comment: I think weblink is no more a part of core joomla. From where did you get that?

Comment: As you say @Amit Ray, Weblinks is no longer part of core Joomla but is available as an option via the JED: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/official-extensions/weblinks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like incorrect permissions have been set at Components -> Weblinks -> Options -> Permissions.

For example, the Public Edit permission by default should be "Inherited" rather than "Allowed".

Comment: The answer from Rocket Theme - where I bought the template:

"Your Joomla ACL seems to be corrupted since it is giving superuser access privileges to everyone (regardless of group) see screenshot (hence why edit button is showing).

I would suggest that your use an extension called "ACLManager" that can repair this - it's not FREE so do make sure it's what you want before purchasing.... "

This answer seems to match the above answers... THANK YOU !!!

Comment: You should be able to reset permissions back to the defaults without purchasing a third party extension.

Comment: I have tried to change permissions. I think they may be really screwed up. I strongly suspect this was an earlier upgrade from 2.5 and the ACL in fact may have become screwed up. A cheaper solution, maybe just turn Weblinks off ( I did ), and just put up a simple article with links within it ( I will do that ). There are only 2 Administrator users in the system, as we don't allow any other users to login. We are hoping that leaving the corrupt? ACL as is may not bite us in the end ? - We can always spend the $20 or so to get the ACL fixed...mmmmm... Thanks to all !